# The firebase CLI is not updating the project folders

Tags: firebase, localhost, command-line-interface

I'm developing a web app using the firebase CLI (`firebase serve`) but when I edit the code and reload my localhost the changes are not applied or it takes a couple of hours. It was applying the changed immediately before.

Is anyone having this sort of trouble or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fixed it by restarting the editor, the terminal and the browser... Still not sure what was going on there.